# Why anchor does not applied to the point?

Tags: openlayers

I have a `feature` as point. I add it into a new layer:

```
 this.sourceLayerEdit = new VectorSource();
    this.vectorLayerEdit = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.sourceLayerEdit,
      zIndex: 9000,
      style: (feature) =>
        styleFeatureFunction(
          feature,
          icon,
          { color: '#cccccc' },
          this.baseHref
        ),
    });
```

The style function is:

```
export const styleFeatureFunction = (
  feature: Feature | FeatureLike,
  icon: Icon,
  options: any,
  baseHref: string
) => {
  const features = feature.get('features');
  const size = features ? features.length : null;

  if (icon) {
    const { anchor, scale, color, src, text } = icon;
    const style = new Style({
      image: new IconOl({
        scale,
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        anchor: [0.5, 145],
        color: options?.color || color,
        src: `${baseHref}assets/images/${src}`,
      }),
    });

    if (text && size) {
      let textvalue: string;
      if (text.seq) textvalue = size + '';
      if (text.text) textvalue = text.text;

      const styleText = new Text();

      if (text.stroke) {
        const stroke = new Stroke({ color: text.stroke });
        if (text.StrokeWidth) stroke.setWidth(text.StrokeWidth);
        styleText.setStroke(stroke);
      }

      if (text.fill)
        styleText.setFill(
          new Fill({
            color: text.fill,
          })
        );

      if (text.font) styleText.setFont(text.font);
      if (text.scale) styleText.setScale(text.scale);
      if (textvalue) styleText.setText(textvalue);

      style.setText(styleText);
    }

    return [
      style,
      new Style({
        image: new Circle({
          radius: 45,
          fill: new Fill({ color: 'transparent' }),
        }),
      }),
    ];
  }
};
```

By click I try to change point position:

```
  this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
     
        const [x, y] = evt.coordinate;

        (
          feature.getGeometry() as any
        ).setCoordinates([x, y]);
    });
```

Problem is when cooridnates of point is changed by click the anchor of point is wrong. The coordinates of click must be in the tails of point (pic. 1)

[image: anchor: options?.anchor || anchor,]

How to fix it?

Comment: To anchor at bottom center use [0.5, 1] with both x and y units fraction

Comment: It works thank you. post is as answer I will accept